# entity framework core migration is not copy my data from database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I get just empty DB, my DB has few rows in every tables, but I get empty tables after migration to new db.

If I have Seed() method, I get just this data but not from my BD.

Comment: The migrations feature enables you to make changes to your model and then propagate those changes to database schema. It is not used to transfer/copy existing data from your existing DB to new DB you create.

Comment: Hmm. I thought it is. Thank you. Could you tell me how to transfer my data?

Comment: Many ways to do this. For example,1) database export and import feature 2) some tools that can transfer data from one database to another etc. You can search and find more approaches to achieve it.